# react ref and query selector all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react and `useRef`

Previously I was checking the rows of a table using the following:

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
```

But now I have multiple tables on my page so I need to use a `ref` to ensure I target the correct `table`.

When I try and use the ref I get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object
>   HTMLTableElement] tr' is not a valid selector.

My code looks like the following:

```
const App = () => {

   const tableRef = React.useRef(null);

   const someMethod = () => {
      // this gives the error specified above
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll(`${testRef.current} tr`);

   }

   return (
     <>
       <table ref={tableRef}>
          //code here
        </table>
        <button onClick={() => someMethod()}>Random Button</button>
     </>
   )
}
```

Can anyone advise how to correctly target the ref in `document.querySelectorAll`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ref.current` is a DOM node (or null). So you need

```
const rows = testRef.current.querySelectorAll('tr');
```

Also you could use `testRef.current.rows` to access rows. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows)

Comment: Will give you the green flag when I can. Very nice, never knew I could access `rows` like that

Comment: @peterflanagan `HTMLTableElement` provides a whole API to manipulate table rows. Check the article I've linked.

Comment: yep, just checked it 

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `window.document.querySelectorAll` within react to access any component you wish.